# Symfony ChoiceType with array containing unique keys and duplicate values

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

It's not uncommon to have an array:

```
$array['hh2643ggwy'] = 'John';
$array['baddeyud'] = 'Jane';
$array['cceuv6vv'] = 'John';
```

Symfony ChoiceType (as a select), for reasons I'll never understand, uses the values as the select option keys!!!!

So with the array above, only one 'John' will be in the select.

Does anyone know of a solution to populate the select per the given array structure?

Two days later...

I live in central US and wanted to go to New York. So I went the California route:

```
    $builder
        ->add('user_id', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => 'Select user',
            'required' => true,
            'choice_label' => function ($choice, $key, $value) use ($array) {
                return $array[$choice];
            },
            'choice_value' => function ($choice) {
                return $choice;
            },
            'choices' => array_keys($array),
            'mapped' => false,
        ]);
```

There's got to be a better solution...

Comment: I understand the problem, but after you get it working, how will a user be able to tell which John they're picking if there are two available?

Comment: which version of symfony you are using ?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I guess the user will have to decide or change the value. All I can do is present a complete selection based on unique ids. After that, it's up to the user.

Comment: @zizoujab I'm using Symfony 5.4, but I see its been an issue for some time. Symfony  is a great framework, but it has some frustrating issues.